# GPU is not available for Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda, conda

I installed Anaconda, CUDA, and PyTorch today, and I can't access my GPU (RTX 2070) in torch. I followed all of installation steps and PyTorch works fine otherwise, but when I try to access the GPU either in shell or in script I get

```py
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
>>> torch.cuda.device_count()
0
>>> print(torch.version.cuda)
None
```

Running `conda list` shows this as my installed package

```sh
cudatoolkit               11.3.1               h59b6b97_2
```

and running `numba -s` in the conda environment shows

```sh
__CUDA Information__
CUDA Device Initialized                       : True
CUDA Driver Version                           : 11030
CUDA Detect Output:
Found 1 CUDA devices
id 0    b'NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070'                              [SUPPORTED]
                      compute capability: 7.5
                           pci device id: 0
                              pci bus id: 1
Summary:
        1/1 devices are supported
```

and all of the tests pass with `ok`. CUDA 11.3 is one of the supported compute platforms for PyTorch and by my GPU and that is the version that I installed.

I already tried reinstalling CUDA, I am on Windows 10, `nvcc --version` shows that CUDA is installed `Build cuda_11.3.r11.3/compiler.29745058_0`

Any suggestions would be helpful

Edit: I am using PyTorch 1.10 installed from the generated command on [their website](https://pytorch.org/). Using `python 3.9.7`. I also installed PyTorch again in a fresh conda environment and got the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried installing Pytorch with older CUDA versions such as 10.1 / 10.2? If your platform supports 11, then it should do so for the older versions as well...

Comment: You are have a version of PyTorch installed which has not been built with CUDA GPU acceleration. You need to install a different version of PyTorch. On CUDA accelerated builds `torch.version.cuda` will return a CUDA version string. On non CUDA builds, it returns `None`

Comment: Open terminal, type `nvidia -smi` to check if nvidia driver is installed successfully or not.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for pointing that out. Changing my PyTorch version seems to have fixed the issue. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Its `nvidia-smi` there is no space between the two words.

Answer (score 4):

- Double check that you have installed pytorch with cuda enabled and not the CPU version
- Open a terminal and run `nvidia-smi` and see if it detects your GPU.
- Double check that your Cuda version is the same as the one required by PyTorch. If you have an older version of Cuda, then download the latest version.

Comment: How to check that I have installed pytorch with cuda enabled and not the CPU version?

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading CUDA to 10.2 and using PyTorch LTS 1.8.2 lets PyTorch use the GPU now. Per the comment from @talonmies it seems like PyTorch 1.10 doesn't support CUDA

Comment: It isn't that Pytorch `1.10 doesn't support CUDA -- it does. It is that the *build* that you had installed didn't have CUDA support compiled in

Comment: I installed the build listed on the homepage and it didn't work. I selected that I was using CUDA and there were no other build options

Comment: It can be that they messed up and are accidentally distributing a non GPU build as a GPU build.

Answer (score 1):

If you use conda, try to update conda. It works for me to install PyTorch 1.10 with CUDA 10.2.

Answer (score 0):

For people coming to this in 2024, you can go to the Pytorch's [get-started site](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) and install the Preview (Nightly) version with `CUDA 12.X`. It worked for me and some other people, according to this [Bug thread on Github](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/112500).

As of Feb. 2024, the command to install Pytorch this way (taken from the above mentioned site) is:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=12.1 -c pytorch-nightly -c nvidia
```